# Import a specific column of a CSV in R

Tags: r, csv, import

We already know how to select the columns of a dataframe in R.

But how about if we want to select which columns of a csv we want to import in the enviroment?

As for example, if I have a csv with four columns separated by an space:

```
IEAL <- read.csv(file="/Directory/ieal.csv", sep=" ")
```

How can I select to import just the second column?

Comment: `IEAL <- read.csv(file="/Directory/ieal.csv", sep=" ")[, 2]`. Although here you are importing everything and then selecting the 2nd column.

Comment: You can specify columns to import using the vroom package: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/#column-selection

Comment: You can use `data.table::fread("/Directory/ieal.csv", select=...)` where `...` is either a char vector of columns to choose or a vector of column numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a column from a file with `read.csv.sql` in package `sqldf`.

First, create a file. In this case it's a CSV file, with the comma as columns separator.

```
write.csv(iris, "iris.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Now read just the second column.

```
library(sqldf)


iris2 <- read.csv.sql(
  file = "iris.csv",
  sql = "select `Sepal.Width` from file")

str(iris2)
#'data.frame':  150 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ Sepal.Width: num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
```

If the separator is a blank space, set `sep = " "`.

```
iris3 <- read.csv.sql(
  file = "iris.txt",
  sep = " ",
  sql = "select `Sepal.Width` from file")

identical(iris2, iris3)
#[1] TRUE
```